# How can I get value of variable depend on another variable In Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

In below PL/SQL, output result was 'TABLE_1' but I need to get value of this variable which is 'WIN' , not print name of variable. How can apply it?

```
DECLARE
TABLE_0 VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT 'LOSE';
TABLE_1 VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT 'WIN';
GUESS   VARCHAR2(10);
X       NUMBER;
BEGIN
  X := 1;
  GUESS := 'TABLE_'||X;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(GUESS);
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking to get an output depending on a variable, but which variable must be used depends on (other) data. This **can** be done in PL/SQL, with what is known as "dynamic" PL/SQL, as shown below. Note that dynamic PL/SQL is not at the beginner level - it's an advanced topic.

```
DECLARE
  TABLE_0 VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT 'LOSE';
  TABLE_1 VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT 'WIN' ;
  X       NUMBER;
  GUESS   VARCHAR2(1000);   -- or CLOB for more generality
BEGIN
  X := 1;
  GUESS := ' DECLARE
               TABLE_0 VARCHAR2(10) := :TABLE_0;
               TABLE_1 VARCHAR2(10) := :TABLE_1;
             BEGIN
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TABLE_' || X || ');
             END;';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE GUESS USING TABLE_0, TABLE_1;
END;
/
```

When I run this code, I get the following response (making sure that I set serveroutput on first, so I can see the output from PUT_LINE):

```
WIN


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Note that `X` can be an argument to a stored procedure, it doesn't have to be hardcoded as you have it here. The same is true of `TABLE_0` and `TABLE_1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't with those two scalar variables, but you could use a [collection](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm):

```
DECLARE
  TYPE T_RESULTS IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  RESULTS T_RESULTS := T_RESULTS();
  X NUMBER;
BEGIN
  RESULTS(1) := 'LOSE';
  RESULTS(2) := 'WIN';

  X := 1;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(X || ': ' || RESULTS(X));

  FOR I IN 1..5 LOOP
    X := CEIL(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 2));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(X || ': ' || RESULTS(X));
  END LOOP;
END;
/

1: LOSE
2: WIN
2: WIN
1: LOSE
1: LOSE
2: WIN
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6fcdc8405007ff5f6371f38f243314a4)

Comment: @psaraj12 - not sure what you mean - the variable to do the lookup in the question is a number, not a string?

Comment: got it, in that case we can use Result(0):='LOSE' and Result(1):='WIN' then OP RESULT(GUESS) or Result(X) will give correct answer

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL does not provide the meta-programming capabilities to be able to interrogate the value of a variable based on the name of the variable - by the time the program is executing the names of the variables are not accessible in the program itself. @AlexPoole has shown one way to do work within these constraints. Another way to do this is to use a collection of strings in which the indexes are also strings:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE tCol_string_idx_string IS
    TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10)
      INDEX BY VARCHAR2(10);

  colGuesses  tCol_string_idx_string;

  X           NUMBER;
  GUESS       VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  colGuesses('TABLE_1') := 'LOSE';
  colGuesses('TABLE_2') := 'WIN';

  X := 1;
  GUESS:= 'TABLE_' || X;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('X=' || X || 
                       '  GUESS=''' || GUESS || '''' ||
                       '  result=''' || colGuesses(GUESS) || '''');

  X := 2;
  GUESS:= 'TABLE_' || X;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('X=' || X || 
                       '  GUESS=''' || GUESS || '''' ||
                       '  result=''' || colGuesses(GUESS) || '''');
END;
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a71f8d695294838124ad2ffefe381353)

Comment: PL/SQL does provide said meta-programming capabilities - I just showed that in my Answer.